# Jqgrid does not initiate server side call

Tags: jqgrid

Sorry to be posting this question. :( But I have spent almost the entire day and need another pair of eyes to look into my code.

OS: Windows
Frameworks: JQuery (latest version), JqGrid (latest version), Spring (latest version)
DB: PostgreSql
Tool: Springsource Tools Suite

When I type the below URL, I get XML data back from the server.
http://localhost:8080/myapp/deliveryJqgridData

But the below jqGrid call does not call the above URL. I dont get any error on Spring TC server. I do get the alert message "enteredJqgrid". The code below is stored in deliveryJqgrid.jsp. The same is accessed through localhost:8080/myapp/deliveryJqgrid.
I have scrambled the column names given below.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            alert("enteredJqgrid");
          $("#deliveryJqgrid").jqGrid({
            url:'deliveryJqgridData',
            datatype: 'xml',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames:['1Col','2Col', '3Col','4Col','5Col','6Col'],
            colModel :[ 
              {name:'1Col', index:'1Col', width:55}, 
              {name:'2Col', index:'2Col', width:90}, 
              {name:'3Col', index:'3Col', width:80, align:'left'}, 
              {name:'4Col', index:'4Col', width:80, align:'left'}, 
              {name:'5Col', index:'5Col', width:80, align:'left'}, 
              {name:'6Col', index:'6Col', width:150, sortable:false} 
            ],
            pager: '#deliveryJqgridPager',
            rowNum:10,
            rowList:[10,20,30],
            sortname: '1Col',
            sortorder: 'asc',
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: 'Delivery List - JQ Grid'
          }); 
        }); 
    </script>
```

I have the below div tags in body section.

```
        <table id="deliveryJqgrid"></table> 
    <div id="deliveryJqgridPager"></div>
```

Thanks for your help in advance.
**Update**

I found the following error on Firebug. Does this give any clue?

```
b.jgrid.format is not a function
```

`[Break On This Error] m+"'>"+b.jgrid.format(a.p.pgtext||"","... class='ui-separator'></span></td>"+`

Comment: Try using a debugger like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) - are you getting a 404 on the request?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I used firebug and it gave the below error under Error tab.     Did this ring a bell?
b.jgrid.format is not a function 
[Break On This Error] m+"'>"+b.jgrid.format(a.p.pgtext||"","... class='ui-separator'></span></td>"+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I was loading /jquery.jqGrid.min.js before i18n/grid.locale-en.js in my script tag. I reversed the order and it worked!

Thanks to everyone for their patience in helping me through this silly mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
$("#deliveryJqgrid").jqGrid({
    url: '/myapp/deliveryJqgridData',
    ...
});
```

EDIT:

Used your code in one of my pages and is correctly invoking the server script. I get 404 because I dont have it as you can see

[image]

Comment: Thanks! for the quick response. I tried the above but it did not work. The view page source confirms that I did change it correctly.

Comment: My view source  <script type="text/javascript">

   $(function(){

    alert("enteredJqgrid");

     $("#deliveryJqgrid").jqGrid({

       url:'/myapp/deliveryJqgridData',

       datatype: 'xml',

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize that I cannot enter new line in comments. It immediately submits it!

Comment: The code seems to be correct. I have pasted your code exactly as is in one of my page and I can see the calls with fiddler returning 404 because I dont have the server script. Try using Fiddler/Firebug to see what's going to happen on the server side.

Comment: Thanks! Firebug's 'Net Tab' shows below URLs but does not show GET deliveryJqgridData.(sorry,new user. So cant post image)

GET deliveryJqgrid;jsessionid=E0CAFC92DD57AD88199DA835349D4928
http://localhost:8080/myapp/deliveryJqgrid;jsessionid=E0CAFC92DD57AD88199DA835349D4928
200 OK

GET jquery-ui.css (304)
GET ui.jqgrid.css (304)
GET jquery.min.js (304)
GET jquery-ui.min.js (304)
GET jquery-ui.panel.js (304)
GET jquery.jqGrid.min.js (304)
GET grid.locale-en.js (304)
GET ui-bg_inset-soft_25_000000_1x100.png (304)
GET ui-bg_glass_20_555555_1x400.png (304) 
GET ui-icons_cccccc_256x240.png (304)

Comment: It seems you are getting `200 OK` as per what you have posted. Which field is the key in your returned Model?

Comment: First I load the JSP deliveryJqgrid from another page. Once that is loaded, it makes a call for deliveryJqgridData to populate Jqgrid. The above 200 OK is for the initial loading page deliveryJqgrid. The page deliveryJqgridData is not called at all. Also, please see the Firebug error message I posted in my main post above.

Comment: I used firebug and it gave the below error under Error tab. Did this ring a bell? 

b.jgrid.format is not a function [Break On This Error] m+"'>"+b.jgrid.format(a.p.pgtext||"","... class='ui-separator'></span></td>"+